# Why doesn't Visual Studio warn me about a null reference exception?

Tags: c#, tostring, nullable, null-conditional-operator

I wonder why Visual Studio 2019 doesn’t complain about this piece of C# code:

```
dynamic deserializedBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
deserializedBody?.date.ToString();
```

Since `deserializedBody?.date` could be `null`, it would mean that the `ToString` method would be applied to something `null`. I think something like this:

```
deserializedBody?.date?.ToString();
```

would be the correct form to use, but Visual Studio doesn’t complain about the first version. Surely I’m missing something about the true nature of this piece of code.

Comment: It is a simple, compact and very cheap way to enforce that the object has a well-defined date value.  Exceptions are your friend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The null-safe dereferencing operator stops evaluation of the whole expression as soon as it hits null. So if `deserializedBody` is null, it won't try to evaluate `date`, and it won't call `ToString()` on anything - so you won't get an exception.

Complete example:

```cs
using System;

class Test
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.UtcNow;

    static void Main()
    {
        Test t = null;
        // No exception thrown
        Console.WriteLine(t?.date.ToString());
    }    
}
```

Here the expression `t?.date.ToString()` is equivalent to:

```cs
t is null ? null : t.date.ToString()
```

(except that `t` is only evaluated once). It's *not* equivalent to

```cs
(t is null ? null : t.date).ToString()
```

... which is what I suspect you were expecting it to do.

But no, this *doesn't* protect against the situation where `deserializedBody` is non-null, but `deserializedBody.date` is null.

If you were expecting a warning due to C# 8 nullable reference types, I believe dynamic expressions are never null-checked. As an example of this, consider:

```cs
class Test
{
    public string? foo;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        dynamic d = t;

        Console.WriteLine(t.foo.Length); // Warning 
        Console.WriteLine(d.foo.Length); // No warning
        Console.WriteLine(d.bar); // No warning for this either
    }
}
```

I *suspect* the reason for this is that the compiler basically has no information about what `d.foo` is. For every case where there's a useful warning, there'd be another case where the warning isn't useful. When you're in dynamic typing territory, you've already accepted a certain degree of risk - it would seem odd to warn that dereferencing `d.foo` is risky when the access of `d.foo` is risky to start with.

Comment: `((dynamic)(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{}")))?.date.ToString()`

Comment: @PauloMorgado: I'm not sure what your comment is intended to tell us.

Comment: The `date` property can and is `null` on that code. There's no way for the compiler to know it can't be `null`. So, it should warn.

Comment: @PauloMorgado: Do you mean with nullable reference types turned on? I'd be very surprised if NRTs did *anything* with dynamic typing, because otherwise every deference would end up requiring `?.`.

Comment: @PauloMorgado: I've added an example and more justification in the answer.